# Customise Visual Studio 2012 installation (C# only)

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is there any way to customise which languages are installed with Visual Studio 2012? I only want C#, no VB or F# etc.

I'm trying to install Visual Studio 2012 Premium RTM.

The first install page I see this:

[image]

and the next I see this:

[image]

but there's no option to choose which languages I want to install :-(

Comment: Completely disgusting stuff from M$ as usual... I don't need F# or VB or C++ and yet they force load 6GB of stuff I don't need to my small SSD drive...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think thats as much customization as your going to get.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/06/04/setup-improvements-for-visual-studio.aspx

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2639283-bring-back-the-visual-studio-installation-customiz

According to those links they [Microsoft] removed then brought back the option for customization.  And what you see there is all you get.  I know my installation of VS 2012 (upgraded express to ultimate) is only taking up 2 gb so IDK why it is saying it needs 6.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2930718-provide-installation-customization-options-to-excl

Comment: @Owen Greg: Well, a complete installation does take up 6 GB or so. Where & how did you check the space taken up by VS 2012?
I suppose you are just taking into consideration the space taken up in 'Program Files'/'Add or Remove Programs'. And thus missing the space taken up in 'Users' & 'Windows' folder to maintain metadata & most importantly the associated assemblies. The assemblies run into several GBs.

Answer (score 2):

I've [raised the point on the Visual Studio installation forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/504ebf41-9179-4acc-a756-e5ef546dc74e/bring-back-custom-install-options-for-languages-in-vs-2012-install),  see what comes of it.