# Possible to install Visual Studio 2012 without C++ support?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

At a current PC I have a very limited disk space and would like to install VS2012 without C++ support which seems to take about 1GB of disk space. Is that possible with this version of Visual Studio? I am quite sure that you could uncheck languages that you didn't want in the past but I can't find this option in VS2012 (actually I'm trying from the "Modify" dialog once VS has been installed, maybe a full reinstall is my option?).

Comment: No C++? Shame on you! [This old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806503/customise-visual-studio-2012-installation-c-only) says no, but I'd swear I've seen it. As a last resort you could uninstall it completely and go for one of the single-language express editions I suppose, but that's a shame when you've paid for the real thing.